# Unhandled Exception: type 'String' is not a subtype of type 'int' of 'index' - Firebase getInitialMessage Flutter

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, push-notification

This is my content get from getInitialMessage using RemoteMessage.data, but I can't extract payload from the below json. I got Unhandled Exception: type 'String' is not a subtype of type 'int' of 'index'.

I was using awesome notifications, that's why I am using this type of json.

```
{content: {"channelKey":"big_picture","payload":{"screen":"retreat-video","links":"https:\/\/www.youtube.com\/watch?v=neFEJxwyYKo"},"thumbNailUrl1":"https:\/\/www.dw.com\/image\/49519617_303.jpg","largeIcon":"https:\/\/cdn.pixabay.com\/photo\/2023\/03\/19\/07\/34\/car-7862030_960_720.jpg","notificationLayout":"BigPicture","autoDismissible":true,"id":"100","title":"Huston! The eagle 
has landed!","body":"A small step for a man, but a giant leap to flutters community!","bigPicture":"https:\/\/cdn.pixabay.com\/photo\/2023\/03\/19\/07\/34\/car-7862030_960_720.jpg"}}
I/flutter (23855): -----------------------------
E/flutter (23855): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(209)] Unhandled Exception: type 'String' is not a subtype of type 'int' of 'index'
```

This is getInitialMessage how to get payload data

```
  FirebaseMessaging.instance.getInitialMessage().then((message) {
      // debugPrint("inside getInitial message");

      if (message.data != null) {
        print("${message.data}");

        

        // ReceivedAction receivedAction = ReceivedAction.fromJson(message.data);
     //    ReceivedAction receivedAction = ReceivedAction.fromJson(message.data);
        print("-----------------------------");
        print("data is here: ${message.data["content"]['payload']}");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try parsing the JSON string in the `content` field into a valid JSON object .

```
FirebaseMessaging.instance.getInitialMessage().then((message) {
  if (message.data != null) {
    print("${message.data}");

    // Parse the content field into a JSON object
    var content = jsonDecode(message.data['content']);

    print("-----------------------------");
    // Access the payload field from the content object
    print("data is here: ${content['payload']}");
  }
});
```